# Change a state when a redux prop is updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have an app in which when a user log in, a few async API calls are made.
These are handled in the index.tsx file.
Once the response arrives, it is stored in the redux store.
This data contains the values to display in a dropdown and is used in another tab that is not visible immediately.
However there is the case when a user is fast enough to click on the tab and displays it before the API response is received.

That means that the data I load in componentDidMount can be incomplete in some cases.

Here is my tab component code:

```
class SearchConditionGroup extends React.Component<Props, State> {
    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            isMounted: false,
            extendData: [],
            isAddAndConditionDropdownOpen: false,
            openAddAndConditionDropdownAboveButton: false,
            searchConditionDropdownOptions: [],
            searchConditions: [],
        }
    }

  componentDidMount = async (): Promise<void> => {        
      try {
          await this.cacheDynamicData();

          // Create an array of `RichOption` objects that the dropdown menu expects (converted from `SearchConditionDropdownItem`/`SearchConditionDropdownSubmenuItem` objects)
          const searchConditionDropdownOptions: Array<RichOption> = await Promise
              .allSettled(SearchConditionsDropdownItems.map(this.searchConditionDropdownMenuItemToDropdownOption)) 
              .then((results: Array<PromiseSettledResult<RichOption>>) => results.filter((result: PromiseSettledResult<RichOption>) => result.status === "fulfilled") as Array<PromiseFulfilledResult<RichOption>>) 
              .then((results: Array<PromiseFulfilledResult<RichOption>>) => results.map((result: PromiseFulfilledResult<RichOption>) => result.value)); 

          // Set the dropdown options to the component state
          this.setState({searchConditionDropdownOptions: searchConditionDropdownOptions, isMounted: true });
      } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
      }
```

And at the end of the component I map state to props in order to access the redux store:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        tags: state.tags,
        categories: state.categories,
    };
  };
  
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SearchConditionGroup);
```

However once the redux store is updated it does not trigger a new mount, just a new update.
I tried re-rendering the state in `componentDidUpdate`, but when I `setState` it creates an infinite loop:

```
componentDidUpdate = async (prevProps: Props, prevState: State): Promise<void> => {

        const searchConditionDropdownOptionsUpdate: Array<RichOption> = await Promise 
            .allSettled(SearchConditionsDropdownItems.map(this.searchConditionDropdownMenuItemToDropdownOption)) 
            .then((results: Array<PromiseSettledResult<RichOption>>) => results.filter((result: PromiseSettledResult<RichOption>) => result.status === "fulfilled") as Array<PromiseFulfilledResult<RichOption>>) 
            .then((results: Array<PromiseFulfilledResult<RichOption>>) => results.map((result: PromiseFulfilledResult<RichOption>) => result.value));
        
        if(prevState.searchConditionDropdownOptions !== this.state.searchConditionDropdownOptions) {   
            this.setState({ searchConditionDropdownOptions: searchConditionDropdownOptionsUpdate })
```

What is the practice to follow in order to update a state once redux store is updated?

Comment: Have you tried disabling the tab you don't want user to click on prior to the data being fetched and populated into the store?

Comment: No, we don't want any blocking actions. If the data comes in then the component should refresh, but the already loaded elements should display

Comment: The component will rerender when you update the state, e.g. `this.setState` in `componentDidMount`. `componentDidUpdate` is the lifecycle method that is called *after* a component rerenders because (a) state or props were updated, or (b) the parent component rerendered its ReactTree.

Comment: Yes, so is there any way to update my states once redux store is updated and trigger a prop change?

Comment: What is updating in the redux store.... that needs to update something in local state? You shouldn't be duplicating any redux state into local component state, and any *derived* "state" should just be computed and also not stored into local component state.

Comment: We're combining the results of 4 API calls to enrich a json object that represents the 3 level structure of a dropdown. If one API call fails, we still want to render the dropdown with the data from the 3 other API calls.
The dropdown can be rendered partially while waiting for the rest of the data to arrive. So it could happen that the dropdown has only data from 1 API call, and then later is updated each time the results from the other calls comes in

Comment: Can you please [edit] the post to include a more complete and comprehensive [mcve] for the code you are working with? *Other than* the `tags` and `categories` state selected from the store I don't see any redux logic in the provided code snippets.